What type of aircraft is this?
Flew very low in circles around my house this morning. I live near Fox Harbour airport in Wallace, Nova Scotia
Click to embiggen


Wow. Thank you for all of that information. It was really something to stand under it and have it pass over head so many times.

I love this site (and many of the sister sites, among them Science Fiction and Fantasy for story identification!) because there is always somebody there who can answer these nagging questions (I had a similar one, and just 20 years ago we would never have known). Kudos to Bianfable here, and have a nice summer in Nova Scotia.

That is a de Havilland Canada Dash 7, a 4-engine turboprop STOL aircraft.
You can see the flight this morning using the Flightradar24 Playback feature:

Flightradar24 does not show the registration of this aircraft, but ADS-B Exchange shows it as C-GCFR:

(jetphotos.com)
This aircraft is operated as a surveillance aircraft by Transport Canada (note the special equipment on top of the fuselage in the picture above):

The iconic red planes of Canada's National Aerial Surveillance Program (NASP) are a pillar in helping Canada stay safe. Since 1991, we've grown — adding new aircraft, new technology and new people — all with the goal of preventing pollution in our waters, protecting our marine environment and endangered marine life, and ensuring a safe and efficient transportation industry along our massive and varied coastlines. [...]
Today's NASP fleet includes aircraft owned and operated by Transport Canada based strategically across Canada for effective monitoring and rapid response to incidents:

Dash 8 based in Moncton serving Central and Eastern Canada [...]

NASP operations rely on a suite of remote sensing equipment that includes:

Side Looking Airborne Radars
Infrared / Ultraviolet Line Scanners
Electro-Optical Infrared Camera Systems
Automatic Identification Systems
Satellite Communications Systems
Geo-coded Digital Camera Systems


(Transport Canada)

Good find, also interesting to see the special configuration with the 'bubble' on top. Link to NASP activities page

@ROIMaison Good point, I added some info on the equipment used from Transport Canada's website.

Only 113 Dash 7s were built. It was a bit of a marketing flop, designed to exploit a prediction that MLS would allow operations from "stub runways" at super busy airports, and which went nowhere. Too much focus on STOL, not enough on efficiency, esp with 4 PT6-50s, chosen because were weren't any up-to-date TPs with the required power to make a Twin work. The Dash 8 was basically a do-over to provide what the regional market really wanted, made possible by P&W's development of the PW-120.
